How to get the time zone from datetime with zoneinfo libraries in Python?
I have a code where I get date and time of different parts of the world with the datetime and zoneinfo libraries in Python. I am able to extract the dates and hourse separately in day, month, year, hour, minute, second and microsecond, but I don't know hoe to extract the Time Zone part of the datetime variable I got. Part of the code is as follows:
import datetime
import zoneinfo

zonaNewYork = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/New_York')

fechaHora_NewYork = datetime.datetime.now(zonaNewYork)
print(type(fechaHora_NewYork))
print("Fecha y Hora en NewYork, EEUU: ")
print(fechaHora_NewYork, "\n")


###### Get Time individually
hora = fechaHora_NewYork.hour
print("Hora: ", hora, "\n")

minutos = fechaHora_NewYork.minute
print("Minutos: ", minutos, "\n")

segundos = fechaHora_NewYork.second
print("Segundos: ", segundos, "\n")

microsegundos = fechaHora_NewYork.microsecond
print("Microsegundos: ",microsegundos, "\n")


###### Get Date individually
year = horafecha_actual.year
print("Año: ", year, "\n")

mes = horafecha_actual.month
print("Mes: ", mes, "\n")

dia = horafecha_actual.day
print("Día: ", dia, "\n")

The code ouputs this:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
Fecha y Hora en NewYork, EEUU:
2024-07-01 17:32:11.454840-04:00

Hora:  17

Minutos:  32

Segundos:  11

Microsegundos:  454840

Año:  2024

Mes:  7

Día:  1

So the question is, how do I get the "-4:00" from "2024-07-01 17:32:11.454840-04:00"?
Thanks in advance

import datetime
import zoneinfo

zonaNewYork = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/New_York')

fechaHora_NewYork = datetime.datetime.now(zonaNewYork)
print(fechaHora_NewYork.strftime('%:z')) # <--- since py 3.12

You can do it yourself, too, by interrogating the tzinfo member of a datetime object:  fechaHora_NewYork.tzinfo

I get ValueError: Invalid format string when I try this.

@MarkRansom, what version of Python? The example above specifies 3.12

3.11 is what I have.  I will say it works with '%z' though, what is the extra : supposed to do?

Never mind, I looked it up.  It's the difference between having ':' in the output or not.

It doesn't work for me in Python 3.12.6 64-bit, it shows nothing but an empty field with el strftime. With the sentence "fechaHora_NewYork.tzinfo" returns "none"

@Jdavid_Ar08, that's behavior I'd expect if you omitted the ZoneInfo argument to the constructor.  I've updated the example with a complete python code that works for me.
